# Unmarshal timestamp using gocql query

Tags: go, cassandra

How to accept Cassandra's timestamp and convert into string using gocql?
What will be the query?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

gocql can read it into a [time.Time](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time), which can then be converted to string by calling [String()](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.String). For example:

```
if err := session.Query(`CREATE TABLE events (
        event text,
        event_time timestamp,
        PRIMARY KEY (event, event_time),
    ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (event_time DESC);
    `).Exec(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal("create table events:", err)
}

tm := time.Now()
if err := session.Query(`INSERT INTO events
        (event, event_time)
        VALUES (?, ?)`,
    "click", tm).Exec(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal("insert into events: ", err)
}

var event_time time.Time

if err := session.Query(`SELECT event_time FROM events LIMIT 1`).
    Consistency(gocql.One).Scan(&event_time); err != nil {
    log.Fatal("select from events:", err)
}

// prints 2014-04-17 01:55:26.434 +0000 UTC
fmt.Printf(event_time.String())
```

Comment: This prints the corresponding UTC timestamp,how can I get the actual value stored in the database. e.g value stored in DB is 2014-04-23 19:12:11-0700 but the value extracted due to time.Time is 2014-04-24 02:12:11.217 +0000 UTC.

Comment: @tushR timestamps do not have (or at least should not have) time zones.  Functionally they are 32 bit ints.  How they are displayed, and what time zone they are in is up to the presenter (in this case, you).  So what is stored in the database is an int that you must convert to a `time.Time` using `time.Unix` unless your driver will handle that for you, then use `time.Format` to display it how you like.